# How can I create the program that encrypts file with 2DES (doubleDES)?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, des

I know doubleDES is not used sine of Meet-in-the-middle Attack but i need to create a program that does that kind of encryption. I tried this but i think im stuck and just cannot figure out what am i missing..

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
DES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
// *****ENKRIPTIMI*****
DES.Key = utf8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 8));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox2.Text);
string permbajtja = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(textBox2.Text, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs1, DES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs);
sw.Write(permbajtja); sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(textBox2.Text);
string msg = stream.ReadToEnd();
stream.Close();
MessageBox.Show(msg);



//*****DEKRIPTIMI*****

DES.Key = utf8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text.Substring(8, 8));
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(textBox2.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
CryptoStream cs1 = new CryptoStream(fs2, DES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(cs1);
string permbajtja1 = sr1.ReadToEnd();
//    MessageBox.Show(permbajtja1);
sr1.Close();
fs2.Dispose();
fs2.Close();


StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(textBox2.Text);
sw1.Write(permbajtja1);
sw1.Flush();
sw1.Close();
```

### **** THE PART ABOVE IS JUST FOR ENCRYPTING *****

The decryption part

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
DES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
// *****ENKRIPTIMI*****
DES.Key = utf8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text.Substring(8,8));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox2.Text);
string permbajtja = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(textBox2.Text, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs1, DES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs);
sw.Write(permbajtja); sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
StreamReader lexo = new StreamReader(textBox2.Text);
MessageBox.Show(lexo.ReadToEnd());
lexo.Close();

////*****DEKRIPTIMI*****

DES.Key = utf8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 8));
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(textBox2.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
CryptoStream cs1 = new CryptoStream(fs2, DES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(cs1);
string permbajtja1 = sr1.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(permbajtja1);
sr1.Close();
fs2.Dispose();
fs2.Close();


StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(textBox2.Text);
sw1.Write(permbajtja1);
sw1.Flush();
sw1.Close();
```

Comment: Can you explain where is your problem, please? Do you get an exception?

Comment: The problem is at the decryption part.. Since I encrypt with the first part of the key and decrypt with the second part, after i start the Decryption, I encypt the text with the second part of the key but i don't get the encrypted part (the part encrypted with the first part of the key)..

Comment: And also i don't get an exception, I don't get the plaintext... but some other ciphertext

Comment: To get ECB mode, simply encrypt twice (second time without padding).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should write the encrypt and the decrypt method:

```
public static string Encrypt(string originalString, byte[] key)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
        cryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(originalString);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        streamWriter.Flush();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string cryptedString, byte[] key)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cryptedString));
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
        cryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
        CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
    {
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Now you can apply twice the encryption method (and of course twice the decryption one) to your string:

```
byte[] key1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678");
byte[] key2 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefgh");

string originalString = "A secret string";
string cryptedString = Encrypt(Encrypt(originalString, key1), key2);
Console.WriteLine("Encrypt message: {0}", cryptedString);
Console.WriteLine("Decrypt message: {0}", Decrypt(Decrypt(cryptedString, key2), key1));
```

Take a look to my code, it may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I think i was not quite clear..
The thing about 2DES is that it works on the princip of DES but uses a 16 character key, which means the key is separated in two parts, you encrypt with the first part and then decrypt with the second part and get the CipherText (since we decrypted with another key the text is still unreadable), this was the Encryption part.
To Decrypt we make the reverse function, we take the CipherText, encrypt it with the second part of the key, and then Decrypt with the first part of the key, and so to arrive to the PlainText.

Comment: My problem was at the Decryption part, i don't the plaintext no matter what i try.. Thanks again for your help but please don't hesitate to help me more with anything you can..

Comment: Basically if you try this with your code

string cryptedString = Decrypt(Encrypt(originalString, key1), key2);
string decryptedString = Encrypt(Decrypt(cryptedString, key1), key2));

IT WON'T WORK.. WHY?

Comment: @ermyab, I am not sure that you are right about 2DES algorithm. Take a look [here](http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/puis/ch06_04.htm). You can find the paragraph 6.4.5.1 which talks about 2DES. It says "_In Double DES, each 64-bit block of data is encrypted twice with the DES algorithm, first with one key, then with another_".

Comment: OH.. well thanks a lot for explanation.. you really helped me a lot but please i have one last question.. i have to make the program using FileStream could you please check my code why won't it work?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mnonzrcxebegsm/DetyraSiguri.rar?dl=0

Here;s the whole code.. please help me!!

Comment: @ermyab, when you return the encrypted bytes in a "string form", you must convert them to a CodeBase64 string. You miss this step in your code...